# Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed

Tags: magento2

After upgrading magento 2.2, this error occurs while opening category pages

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.
Line: 925


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.
Line: 925

#0 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/adventure...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load()
#9 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#10 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#11 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(509): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#12 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(467): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute('body', 'class')
#13 /home/adventure/public_html/app/code/Sm/ShopBy/Controller/Category/View.php(205): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass('page-products')
#14 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View->execute()
#15 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/adventure/public_html/generated/code/Sm/ShopBy/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php(26): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#19 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/adventure/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#28 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/adventure/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30 /home/adventure/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#31 {main}
```

Please ,give solution as soon as possible

Comment: Remove your custom theme and check with default luma theme? If it's still not working properly then disable the custom module and check.

Comment: This is not a bug, those attributes are not allowed when using referenceBlock and you should locate them in your code a remove them.

Comment: Refer the answer you can help for same.

 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281010/magento-framework-config-dom-validationexception-element-referenceblock-at/281018#281018