# (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed

Tags: magento2, frontend

I have this problem and I can't locate where the problem is :

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed. Line: 1124
```

This problem occurs as a connected customer, when I try to access the invoice for a test order.

Here is what I tried to do to solve the problem by following a lot of topics on this forum:

- setup:di:compile
- Delete the content of /pub/static/frontend
- Deploy static content

Nothing works.

Note that I searched my XML for a referenceBlock with a class attribute, but I didn't find anything. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place?

The directories scanned to find the error: 
- /app/code
- /app/design

Can someone explain to me how to locate this error more precisely? Or help me solve it?

EDIT : I made : `grep -r -i --include \* '<referenceContainer' mySiteDirectory/`
And there is no referenceBlock with "class" attribute.

EDIT 2 : With Luma theme, I have same problem. So I suppose it's coming from a module.

So... What to do please ?

Magento version 2.3.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check any thirdparty module installed via composer? location should be 'vendor'?

Comment: Oh gosh... No. I check and I will let you know.

Comment: no referenceContainer with "class" attribute in vendor :(

Comment: I made : grep -r -i --include \* '<referenceContainer' mysiteDirectory/ 
I found nothing...

Comment: Try grep -H -r '<referenceContainer' vendor/

Comment: I tried, not better :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error would suggest invalid XML in your theme and / or extensions.

There is a plugin for PHPstorm editor

https://github.com/magento/magento2-phpstorm-plugin

You can then generate XML URN map to validate against.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/101524/70343

Or better yet you can scan your code. I was going to type an answer on how to use it but then I came across this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227343/70343

The part you are interested in is 'How to use PhpStorm code inspector to validate project xml-files'

Let me know if any detail gets lost in translation.

But basically after generating the URN you can scan your XML code.

[image: Sceenshot of me scanning XML code]

Comment: Thank you very much for all your information. I have a problem with phpstorm. When I launched inspection and it find 5953 errors... 
I assumed that it was necessary to regenerate the URN map. 
I tried to click on the "**Regenerate urn map**" button but nothing is happening.

Comment: Ok I found why... I'm working on preprod server. I'm not in local... So Magento 2 Module for phpstorm cannot help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an issue in one of your `xml` files as you can not use class on the `referenceBlock`. Please check your theme. You can help for fixed issue.

**Refer for further information:**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: Hello @Kirti
I know that. As explained in my initial post, I searched everywhere a XML file were a referenceBlock have an attribute 'class'. But nothing.

This is why I posted here.

Thanks,